# How to make optionally generated class attribute value using XSLT

Tags: php, xslt

I'm gonna using XSLT and I cannot figure out how can I generate dynamically appended class name. Like `class="has-title column-4"`, I want to create whitespace-seperated classic class value.

```
// Original XML string..
<contents>
    <box type="list" mark="kr-con">
        <li>test texts..</li>
        <li>test texts..</li>
        ..
        <li>test texts..</li>
    </box>
</contents>
```

After XSLTProcessing.. I want to get,

```
<div class="box box-list column-1">
    <li>test texts..</li>
    <li>test texts..</li>
    .. (processed elements)
    <li>test texts..</li>
</div>
```

In original xml, `box[@type]` has default value `list`, so the original xml string doesn't have this attribute though the result have `box-list` class.
Also, `box[@column]` attribute doesn't exists but has default value `1` and it leads to `column-1` class.

..

something like that..

I've tried so many hours and I don't think I can handle this.. XSL thing. Very frustrates.. but still need..

How can I generate class value?

I try to make some variable using `<xsl:variable>` tag but it goes wrong more and more..

---

After reviewing answers and some try.. I got below..

```
<!-- figure 처리 -->
<xsl:template match="figure">
    <!-- align 속성 처리 -->
    <xsl:variable name="align">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(@align) and parent::p and position()=1">
                <xsl:value-of select="'right'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="not(@align)">
                <xsl:value-of select="'center'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="@align"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- width 처리 -->
    <xsl:variable name="width">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(@width)">
                <xsl:value-of select="'width-6'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="@width"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- 주 요소 처리 -->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="parent::li">
            <img src="{@url}" class="width-12"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <img src="{@url}" class="align-{@align} {@width}"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

lol~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I really get what you are trying to do, but this should give you an example to start.

In XSLT 1.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="contents/box">
    <xsl:variable name="box">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@type='list'">
                <xsl:value-of select="'box-list'"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="col">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@column">
                <xsl:value-of select="@column"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="'1'"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <div class="{concat('box',' ',$box,' ','column-',$col)}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="li"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3MEcZxw

Comment: Thanks and I remember you. I believe you teach me many times on this community. Much appreciate all your effort. I solve this problem with your hint.